# Where should I post a programming question without code or an algorithm?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I have a problem which I want to solve using programming.
I have sample input/output data, but I don't have a good algorithm.

As I don't have some code, where should I post about the problem?

Comment: @gnat Yes. As I don't have code I cant post it on SO or Code Review. That's why I came here asking.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow does not require that questions include code. General algorithm questions are allowed.

Related tags:

- [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)
- [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic)

Related

- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691)